# Will a Greedy algorithm give a correct result for minimum partition?

Tags: algorithms, greedy-algorithms, partitions

Will a greedy method of picking the item that causes the largest difference each time lead to the optimal result in the minimum partition problem?

Let's say I have a set $\{a_1,a_2,a_3,...a_n\}$, now I have to divide it into two subsets so that the difference between the sums of the two subsets is the minimum possible.

**Greedy Method:**

I have the given set of numbers and an empty set. On each iteration, I select the number from the first set and check which causes the minimum difference and put that into the second set and repeat the process again.

For example: let us say I have to partition $\{1,2,3,4\}$ into two subsets so that their respective sums are minimum.

So using the above method I would do the following steps:

Select the number that causes the min diff so far ie.

$\{2,3,4\}$ and $\{1\}$ diff = $9$

$\{1,3,4\}$ and $\{2\}$ diff = $6$

$\{1,2,4\}$ and $\{3\}$ diff = $4$

$\{1,2,3\}$ and $\{4\}$ diff = $2$

so the minimum is $\{1,2,3\}$ and $\{4\}$

I use the above configuration and repeat the same process, and I land up with the partition $\{2,3\}$ and $\{4,1\}$ which has a difference of $0$ and is the correct answer.

**So, assuming the numbers given are all positive integers, will the greedy method work for all inputs or will it fail for some.** **Is dynamic programming the only way to get the optimal solution?**

Comment: Your greedy method seems to be similar to [this algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem#The_greedy_algorithm), which is only an approximation method. The Wikipedia page also gives a counter-example for optimality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not always lead to the optimal solution. For example for input $\{1,11,16,19,20,30,36,40,41\}$ it gives $\{1,11,16,19,20,36\}$ and $\{30,40,41\}$ with a difference of 8, while a difference of 0 is possible: $\{1,40,36,30\}$ and $\{41,20,16,11,19\}$

Comment: This answer is correct for the "naive" greedy solution, but you might also consider the same algorithm, but with a sorted input. With the pre-sorted greedy algorithm, the input from this answer actually does produce the optimal result.

However, consider the input {4, 5, 6, 7, 8}. 8 and 7 will be put immediately in separate sets, but they need to be in the same set to sum to the remaining 15. The pre-sorted greedy algorithm will end with {8, 5, 4} and {7, 6} with a difference of 4.

Answer (score 1):

As Jeff Erickson says in his [book](http://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms/), "greedy algorithms never work". (Except in the --rare-- cases where they do, and they offer simple, efficient approximations to many NP-hard search problems, see for instance Kun's ["When Greedy Algorithms are Good Enough: Submodularity and the (1 – 1/e)-Approximation"](https://jeremykun.com/2014/07/07/when-greedy-algorithms-are-good-enough-submodularity-and-the-1-1e-approximation/), check also Krause and Golovin's [survey](https://las.inf.ethz.ch/files/krause12survey.pdf) for more in-depth discussion.